# Why is React throwing an error. I'm trying to wrap the application in a provider. React version 18 ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router-dom

```html
import React, { FC } from 'react'

const Feed: FC = () => {
    return <div>Feed</div>
}

export default Feed
```

Below is the code of how I set up the store and how I connected the Provider

```css
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { registerReducer } from '../slice/registerSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { register: registerReducer },
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

```html
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    {/* {/* <Route exact path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} /> */}
                    <Route path='/' element={<AuthScreen />} />
                    <Route path='/registration' element={<RegisterScreen />} />
                    <Route path='/feed' element={<Feed />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

I tried swapping BrowserRouter and Provider but still didn't help

Comment: Your issue is coming from somewhere else than your screen shots. Can you drop your 3 screens components as well? Not as screenshot but as code please

Comment: Please post your code instead of links to images of your code. It really makes our job of helping you harder than it should. You can refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more instructions.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the code now.

Comment: What is the definition of `Provider` and can you show us the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: Add again the error + authscreen + register screen + feed please

Comment: Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons.
When I remove the provider, the error disappears if that

Comment: I just noticed that when I remove everything and leave only the Provider inside which there is only feed, the error remains and it is the same! So it's in the provider or in the store

Comment: Like I said earlier, this error may be caused by another component than your App.

Comment: Can you add the Feed comp please ?

Comment: I added only Feed which is an empty component

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. She was dumb to the core. I just installed redux in package.json backend and not frontend